# Division not showing! Why?

Tags: html, css

So i have been working on making a website for me and my friends, and until now i have made the menu bar, and a communication space ( with `<div>`s). But I don't seem to make the second div to show up. Where is my problem? Why doesn't it show up?
Here's my code:

```css
#MenuBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: center;
  display: fixed;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
#MenuTabs {
  width:  75%;
  height: 75%;
  color: white;
  position: center;
}
#Messenger {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  display: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!-- The menu tab -->
<div id="MenuBar">
  <table id="MenuTabs" cellspacing="1%" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>Lessons</td>
      <td>Playground</td>
      <td>About</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Communication Tab-->
<div id="Messenger"></div>
```

As you can see, it only shows the menu bar, but it doesnt show the white-background div. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: There are no such properties as `position:center` or `display:fixed`. Validate your code first.

Comment: Try putting content in it

Comment: Block boxes without content nor definite height are 0px tall. Your percentage is not definite because it's in-flow and the parent has auto height.

Comment: And theres no display: fixed its position: fixed

Comment: I would recommend you to validate if the CSS that you've is proper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk7jcj9b/1/).

The reason why the second div was not showing up was because, you were using `%` as height for the `<div>`s. For using `%` as height, you'll have to apply height in `%` to all its parents. Hence, for it to work, you'll have to specify the height of `body` and `html` in `%`.

Thus, you'll have to add the below given style too to your CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That helped! Thank you!

Comment: Oh great.. :) Glad that it helped you.. :)

Comment: @AlbanianGamerYT Could you please mark the answer as accepted if it really helped you..

Comment: Will do it in 8 min (it says i can do it only after 8 min).

Comment: ya fine.. Thankyou.. :)